# Maximum update depth exceeded When I try to Create Login Form

Tags: reactjs, render

I want to Redirect to login page if the state has user id
I Check that condition inside the render method is the userId is null it works fine but when userId is not null send me this error..

Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Any Way to fix this? ( I Don't want to use Redux )

this is my some of my Code

My State....

```
state = {
name: "",
email: "",
password: "",
password2: "",
errors: null,
image: null,
imageName: null,
token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
userId: localStorage.getItem('userId')
};
```

onSubmit function ..

```
onSubmit = async e => {

e.preventDefault();
this.setState({
  errors: null
});
if (this.state.password !== this.state.password2) {
  this.setState({
    errors: "Password and Confirm Password Are Invalid"
  });
} else {
  const newUser = {
    email: this.state.email,
    password: this.state.password,
    name: this.state.name,
    image: this.state.imageName,
  };

  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    };
    const body = newUser;
    const res = await axios.post('api/addUser', body, config);
    var token = res.data.token;
    var decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    const userId = decoded.user.id;
    await localStorage.setItem('userId', userId);
    console.log(res.data.token);
    await localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
    await this.setState({
      token: token,
      userId: userId
    });
    this.setState({
        token: res.data
    })

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
};

render() {
if(this.state.userId !== null){
  return (
    <Redirect to="/login" />
  )
}
return (
  <div>Welcome </div>
```

)
}

Comment: That's not your code. That's "some of your code", and doesn't really explain anything. Please show the [mcve] based on your code.

Comment: Is `userId` in a state?

Comment: yes userId is in the state

Comment: Why would you redirect the user to log in when there is a userId present in the state? Maybe the issue here is that it keeps redirecting to login and back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on available code, it seems that you need `this.state.userId` in your `if()` condition. setState() is a function so remove it from there.

Complete code will be helpful to see whats actually going on.